# YouTube API volume control

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I have an embedded iframe using the YouTube API.

I also have a LastFM API embedded which displays which song is currently playing.  If no song is playing then it disappears using CSS.

What I want to happen is when the song disappears (isn't playing) the iframe has full volume but when the songs are playing the iframe is muted.  The songs change on the page dynamically with ajax.

Right now I have the volume changing correctly between 0 and 100 but it needs a page reload for the iframe to take on the new volume.

I'm not sure if I this is possible with the YouTube API dynamically without a page reload.

Below is the code:

HTML

```html
<div id="newsPlayer"></div>

<!--Spotify-->
<div id="spotify">
 <img id="spotifyLogo" src="/img/spotifyLogo.png">
 <p>Currently listening to: <p id="track"></p> on Sams's Spotify </p>
 <img id="artwork">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function refreshMusic() {
  $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false,
    complete: function () {
      setTimeout (refreshMusic, 1000);
    }
  })


username="*******";
key="************************";



$.get( "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=" + username + "&api_key=" + key + "&format=json", function( spotifyData ) 
{


    if (typeof spotifyData.recenttracks.track[0]["@attr"] != "undefined")
    {
        artist=spotifyData.recenttracks.track[0].artist["#text"];
        track=spotifyData.recenttracks.track[0].name;
        album=spotifyData.recenttracks.track[0].album["#text"];
        artwork=spotifyData.recenttracks.track[0].image[1]["#text"];
        $("#artwork").attr("src", artwork).removeClass("hideArtwork");
      $("#track").html(track + " by " + artist + " from " + album);
      window.volume = "0";
  
  
  }
  else {
    $("#artwork").addClass("hideArtwork");
    $("#track").html("Nothing");
    window.volume = "100";
    
  }

  
});


});


//YouTube API

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


//This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) after the API code downloads.
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    
    player = new YT.Player('newsPlayer', {

        videoId: '9Auq9mYxFEE',
        playerVars: {'autohide': 0,
                    'cc_load_policy': 0,
                    'controls': 1,
                    'disablekb': 1,
                    'iv_load_policy': 3,
                    'modestbranding': 1,
                    'rel': 0,
                    'showinfo': 0,
                    'autoplay': 1,
                    'm':0
                    
                    },
                    events: {
                      'onReady': function(newsVolume){
                        newsVolume.target.setVolume(window.volume);
                      },
                      
                      
                    }
    });

}


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  event.target.setVolume(window.volume);
  // event.target.playVideo();
}
```

The window.volume is passing the correct volume into the Youtube API but like I said I need it to change the volume without a page refresh.

I feel like I'm pretty close but can't get over the final hurdle!

Thanks!

Comment: You have design issues. I don't see that `volume` is a property of window. You want to call the same function that you load your AJAX with? Expensive. You should run your jQuery ready `$(function(){})` inside `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady`. `.ajaxSetup` only once, not recursively. Just comments.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was very close and all that was needed was the following:

Runs or "checks" for change every half second and reacts accordingly.

```
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    
    player = new YT.Player('newsPlayer', {

        videoId: '9Auq9mYxFEE',
        playerVars: {'autohide': 0,
                    'cc_load_policy': 0,
                    'controls': 1,
                    'disablekb': 1,
                    'iv_load_policy': 3,
                    'modestbranding': 1,
                    'rel': 0,
                    'showinfo': 0,
                    'autoplay': 1,
                    'm':0
                    
                    },
                    events: {
                      // 'onReady': function(newsVolume){
                      //   newsVolume.target.setVolume(volume);
                      // },
                      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
                      
                    }
    });



function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if($("#artwork").hasClass("hideArtwork")){
    player.unMute();
    // alert("nothing is playing on music");
  }
  else
  {
        player.mute();
        // alert("music is playing");
        
  }
}

setInterval(onPlayerStateChange, 500);

}
```